# The following program generates a compile time error, it says -> type politics does not take parameters

Tags: java

According to my book it is ok! It says if we write `<classname>` with the method then we don't need to cast the `Object` parameter. Why am I getting the error??

```
import java.util.*;

interface politics {    //interface
    void politician(Object obj);
}  

class obama implements politics <obama>  //class
{  
    String job;
    public void politician(obama p) {
        if(p.job.equals("president")) {
            System.out.print("You are right Obama is Mr. PRESIDENT");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("So you say Obama is a "+job.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}

class interface2 {   //class
    public static void main(String args[]) {    //main
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        obama o=new obama();
        System.out.println("president or citizen?");
        String s=in.next();
        o.job=s;
        o.politician(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: please follow Java's naming conventions.

Comment: `According to my book it is ok!` I doubt it. Show us what is written in the book.

Comment: Also read: [How do I compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis here's the link http://s22.postimg.org/8t1xamx81/IMG_1347.jpg

Comment: Please tell what is wrong? Is there a compiler error? Where? Does it do something else (what) than you would expect it to do (what)?

Comment: Yeah that example is completely different than what you are doing. Have you looked up the error `type ... does not take parameters`?

Comment: Have you looked at how the Comparable interface is defined?

Answer (score 2):

Your interface `politics` is not generic. In your code it should look like this:

```
interface politics<T> {
    void politician(T obj);
}
```

It's just a very short answer, for sure you should read the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) first, then try the examples from the tutorial and then return back to your code.

The difference between your code and your book is that `Comparable` is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) like this:

```
public interface Comparable<T>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain the difference?

Comment: yes but why is it not working with the Object type parameter?

Comment: Please **study** the tutorial first. You would not be able to understand my answer before it. If you have still questions *after* studying the tutorial, feel free to ask. You are asking me to explain you the differentials before understanding the multiplication :)